# how render string to html link

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink

I send some message to email as below:

```
string link = "http://localhost:1900/ResetPassword/?username=" + user.UserName + "&reset=" + HashResetParams( user.UserName, user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() );
email.Body = link;
```

This string was sent to email, but shown as string, not as link, I want send it as link to click.

Comment: You should make the link expire by adding a signed timestamp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
string link = String.Format("<a href=\"http://localhost:1900/ResetPassword/?username={0}&reset={1}\">Click here</a>", user.UserName, HashResetParams( user.UserName, user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() ));
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap `link` in an anchor tag:

```
string link = '<a href="http://......">Click here to reset your password</a>';
```

and

```
email.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Or combine them together using string concatenation and feed into `email.Body`.  An email body is HTML, so it wont be a link unless you tell it to be one. Also, don't forget to *tell* it that the body is HTML, like I always do.

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel I forget that every time.

Answer (score 3):

Make it a link with the `a` HTML tag. And don't forget to set the `MailMessage` as HTML body:

```
string link = "http://localhost:1900/ResetPassword/?username=" + user.UserName + "&reset=" + HashResetParams( user.UserName, user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() );
email.Body = "<a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";
email.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string link = "<a href=http://localhost:1900/ResetPassword/?username=" + user.UserName + "&reset=" + HashResetParams( user.UserName, user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + "> Link Text Here </a>");
```

It doesn't know that it's a link :)

Answer (score 2):

Changes the email body from Plain text to Html and generate the link using an `<a>` element

```
string link = @"<a href="www.mylink.com">link</a>"

email.IsBodyHtml = true;
```