# Trigger a mail from another mail body on clicking link

Tags: c#, outlook

**Step** **1**: I have a requirement like On clicking a button in my Application, Mail should be triggered to respective person in To list.

**Step** **2**: That Mail item should contain one link like "Click here to approve".

**Step** **3**: On clicking that link, Another Mail item should open with To: xxx@xxx.com, CC:yyy@yyy.com, subject etc...

I am done with Step 1 and Step 2. But how to do Step 3.

Note : It is an C# application.

I am using below C# code

```
 Body = "Hi, "
 Body += "%0D The Deal - " + ClientName + ", has been Assigned to you  %0D%0D"
 Body += "Expected Signature Date : " + SignDate + " %0D"
 Body += "Expected Funding Date   : " + FundingDate + " %0D%0D"
 Body += "Please, click the below link to view the details. %0D%0D"
 Body += PathName + "%0D"
 Body += "<a href=mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=Subject&body=Body> Click here to send mail</a>"

 Body = Body.Replace("&amp;", " ")
 Body = Body.Replace("#", "")
 sMsg = User.Redirect("mailto:" + cc + "?Subject=" + Subject + "&body=" + Body)
```

Redirect Function:

```
Public Function Redirect(ByVal PageName As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("window.location.href='" + PageName + "'; ")
    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

If i use the Outlook dll How to open the Mail item.

```
Eg: Mailitem.Send() will send the mail. But i need to open the mail item.
```

Comment: You want a mail that contains a link that will open another mail?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application ();
Outlook._MailItem mailItm = ( Outlook._MailItem)app.CreateItem ( Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem );
mailItm.To = "xxx@xxx.com";
mailItm.Cc = "yyy@yyy.com";
mailItm.Subject = "Some Subject";
// body, bcc etc...
mailItm.Display ( true );
```

If you are clicking on a link to send email with filling *(To, Subject, Cc, etc.,*) without using asp.net, you can do something like following using [mailto](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto):

```
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com?Subject=Some%20Subject&Cc=yyy@yyy.com>
Click here to send mail
</a>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where to give this <a href> tag?.. Do you want me to give with in the body in my c# application. string Body = "" ; Body = "Hi"; Body += "< ahref = mailto:xxx@xxx.com> Click here to send mail </a>"

Comment: Yes, In the body you can give.

Comment: Sorry to ask ... Can you give me the exact syntax in the Body+= <a href....????>. Because i am not getting properly in Mail body. It is displaying a href as a string in the body content.

Comment: Post your code and update your question that you tried till now.

Comment: Updated my question. I am getting string like "Body> Click here to send mail</a> " in my message body.

Comment: In `Body` first just try with that `Body += "<a href=mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=Subject&body=Body> Click here to send mail</a>"` and ignore other body parts and check it out whether it works.

Comment: Same output. I am getting string "Body>Click here to send mail</a>" as a body. I removed all the body contents and used only Body = "<a href=mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=Subject&body=Body> Click here to send mail</a>" Is there any problem with Redirect function?

Comment: Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto link and you get to know where you made mistake. Also, you can edit and try according your expected result in that page.

Comment: Refer to `Nick Miceli's` answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975483/how-render-string-to-html-link question.

Comment: I used the correct syntax referred Nick Miceli. Error message is popping up "Command Line Argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using"