# Anchor link in Mail body

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, outlook

Step 1: I have a requirement like On clicking a button in my Application, Mail should be triggered to respective person in To list.

Step 2: That Mail item should contain one link like "Click here to approve".

Step 3: On clicking that link, Another Mail item should open with To: xxx@xxx.com, CC:yyy@yyy.com, subject etc...

I used the below code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sMsg = "";
    string cc = "abc@abc.com";
    string Subject = "Test";
    string Body = "<a href=\"mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=subject\">Click here to send mail</a>";
    sMsg = Redirct("mailto:" + cc + "?Subject=" + Subject + "&body=" + Body);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "showalert", sMsg,true);
}

    public string Redirct(string pagename)
    {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("window.location.href='" + pagename + "'; ");
    return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Above code throws error like "Command Line Argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using"
What is the issue?

Comment: What is there here that isn't worth putting in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482745/trigger-a-mail-from-another-mail-body-on-clicking-link)?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment, but cant because i dont have enough rep. But i noticed you are escaping the "" in the href, why not use '' instead? Not sure if this is the problem but escaping the characters seems kinda useless to me here.

Comment: Are you suggesting this like removing escape - string Body = "<a href=""mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=subject"">Click here to send mail</a>";?

Comment: nonono. like this : "<a href='mailto: xxx.xxx@ge.com?Subject=subject'>Click here to send mail</a>"

You did however do this in  sb.Append("window.location.href='" + pagename + "'; "); Makes me really curious why you escaped it in the "String Body"

Comment: No it is not working. No outlook mail is opening.

Comment: Than it will probably be because outlook doesnt accept html code cause it could be used for wrong

Comment: Is there any other way to do?

Comment: You can try just add it as text, most newer browsers will still change it for you. Other than that, i dont know sorry